# React owl.carousel $ not defined in preview but working in edit mode

Tags: jss, react

I'm having an error right now with owl-carousel. I have it imported in some of my components in react jss and it is throwing error when I'm on Preview in Experience Editor but working perfectly when on Edit.

I looked into this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49655120/react-owl-carousel-not-defined but the answers are already in my jss app. I'm wondering if someone have experienced with owl carousel or other package do you mind sharing your solution.

I'm using Sitecore 9.2 by the way.

Thank You!